# how to convert this model into non editable model in admin of django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I create a model but I need a non-editable model. When I visit the model it's just displaying text, not giving any option of update the record in admin panel.

**model.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

While searching I get information about readonly but I do not still understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. One, make [`editable=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#editable) for all the fields, then it will not be edible anywhere(modelform and adminsite):

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(editable=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False)
    message = models.TextField(editable=False)
```

Two, in adminsite, use [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message')

admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```

Comment: Second method, I need to write in admin.py or models.py??

Comment: You need to write in admin.py file